# Unable to do web scrape as table hidden

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried to **scrape** from this website https://chanakyya.com/Election-Results?electionType=Assembly. But I am unable to access the table for web **scraping** by doing inspection.

Comment: What so far you have tried you need `selenium` for that  from`beautifulsoup` you will not get any output as input is required so try from selenium

Comment: Thanks @BhavyaParikh I have only tried beautifulsoup yet, I will now try selenium

Comment: What exactly you want to find from url can you specify?

Comment: I wanted to extract polling booth table for Uttar pradesh state and assembly constituency ajgara(sc) for all polling booths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the json data that populates the table and just read into a dataframe.

Note: I used a package `choice` to get input for the specific state:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

#pip install choice
import choice

states = requests.get('https://chanakyya.com/Chanakya/states.json').json()

state_list = [x['stateDisplayName'] for x in states]
state_choice = choice.Menu(state_list).ask()

stateName = [x['stateName'] for x in states if x['stateDisplayName'] == state_choice][0]

url = f'https://chanakyya.com/Chanakya/{stateName}/{stateName}.json'
resultsData = requests.get(url).json()


tables = {}
for key, value in resultsData['ELECTION_DATA']['stateLevelData'].items():
    table = pd.DataFrame(value)
    tables[key] = table
 
for key, table in tables.items():
    print(f'*** {key} ***')
    print(table,'\n\n') 
    

    
# Assembly Data
assembly_list = resultsData['ASSEMBLY_NAME_DATA'].keys()
assembly_choice = choice.Menu(assembly_list).ask()
assembly_choice = resultsData['ASSEMBLY_NAME_DATA'][assembly_choice].split('.json')[0]

assembly_url = f'https://chanakyya.com/Chanakya/{stateName}/AssemblyData/{assembly_choice}_Details.json'
resultsAssemblyData = requests.get(assembly_url).json()

print(resultsAssemblyData)
```

**Output:**

```
Make a choice:
 0: Andhra Pradesh
 1: Assam
 2: Bihar
 3: Chhattisgarh
 4: Goa
 5: Gujarat
 6: Haryana
 7: Himachal Pradesh
 8: Jammu & Kashmir
 9: Jharkhand

Enter number or name; return for next page

? 

 0: Karnataka
 1: Kerala
 2: Madhya Pradesh
 3: Maharashtra
 4: New Delhi
 5: Odisha
 6: Punjab
 7: Rajasthan
 8: Tamilnadu
 9: Telangana

Enter number or name; return for next page

? 

 0: Uttarakhand
 1: Uttar Pradesh
 2: West Bengal

Enter number or name; return for next page

? 1

*** 2009_Parliament ***
   partyName  numberOfSeatLeading  votePercentage
0        BSP                  100           27.42
1         SP                  118           23.26
2        INC                   95           18.26
3        BJP                   62           17.50
4        IND                    5            4.53
5        RLD                   21            3.27
6       PECP                    1            0.98
7         AD                    0            0.85
8       SBSP                    0            0.55
9      JD(U)                    0            0.30
10      RSBP                    1            0.28
11       JPS                    0            0.20
12       CPI                    0            0.16
13        MD                    0            0.12
14       IJP                    0            0.11
15      RTKP                    0            0.11
16    RPI(A)                    0            0.10
17      PMSP                    0            0.10
18       ASP                    0            0.07
19      EKSP                    0            0.05
*** 2012_Assembly ***
   partyName  numberOfSeatLeading  votePercentage
0         SP                  224           29.13
1        BSP                   80           25.91
2        BJP                   47           15.00
3        INC                   28           11.65
4        IND                    6            4.14
5       PECP                    4            2.35
6        RLD                    9            2.33
7         AD                    1            0.90
8        GED                    2            0.55
9        NCP                    1            0.33
10      IEMC                    1            0.25
11       CPI                    0            0.13
12      CPIM                    0            0.09
*** 2014_Parliament ***
   partyName  numberOfSeatLeading  votePercentage
0        BJP                  328           42.32
1         SP                   42           22.19
2        BSP                    9           19.63
3        INC                   15            7.48
4        IND                    0            1.75
5        AAP                    0            1.02
6         AD                    9            1.01
7        RLD                    0            0.86
8       NOTA                    0            0.74
9       PECP                    0            0.62
10       QED                    0            0.44
11      BMUP                    0            0.19
12       CPI                    0            0.16
13      SBSP                    0            0.14
14      AITC                    0            0.13
15       RPD                    0            0.12
16     JD(U)                    0            0.07
17       RUC                    0            0.07
18       SHS                    0            0.04
19        LD                    0            0.04
20       NAP                    0            0.04
21      BSCP                    0            0.04
22        MD                    0            0.03
*** 2017_Assembly ***
                              partyName  numberOfSeatLeading  votePercentage
0                                   BJP                  312           39.70
1                                   BSP                   19           22.20
2                                    SP                   47           21.80
3                                   INC                    7            6.20
4                                   IND                    3            2.60
5                                   RLD                    1            1.80
6                                    AD                    9            1.00
7                                  SPSP                    4            0.71
8  Nirbal Indian Shoshit Hamara Aam Dal                    1            0.60
9                                  PECP                    0            0.30
*** 2019_Parliament ***
  partyName  numberOfSeatLeading  votePercentage
0       BJP                  275           49.80
1       BSP                   65           19.40
2        SP                   40           18.10
3       INC                    8            6.30
4       RLD                    4            1.71
5      ADAL                    9            1.20
6       JDL                    2            0.20
```